# Parameter Does Not Work in MDX Subselect Filter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, mdx, sql-server-2016

I have the following MDX query:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    Measures.[Enrolments] ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY 
    ( STRTOMEMBER(@FromISOYear, CONSTRAINED) : 
    STRTOMEMBER(@ToISOYear, CONSTRAINED) ) ON ROWS
FROM (
 SELECT
      Filter
      (
            [Term Start Date].[ISO Year].Children *
            [Term Record Creation].[ISO Year].Children *
            [Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Number Of Year].Children
       ,
        Cint([Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Number Of Year].CurrentMember.Member_Key) <= Cint( STRTOMEMBER(@ToISOWeekNumberOfYear, CONSTRAINED) )
        OR
        Cint([Term Record Creation].[ISO Year].CurrentMember.Member_key) < Cint([Term Start Date].[ISO Year].CurrentMember.Member_key)
      ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Enrolments]
);
```

Basically, the filter expression works when `ISO Week Number of Year` is not a parameter e.g. if I change the filter expression to say `[ISO Week Number of Year] <= 7` it delivers correct results. When I pass the same value from SSRS as a parameter, I get incorrect results - the filter doesn't appear to be applied.

Could someone please explain why this is and provide a fix?

Comment: How do you define the value property of the parameter? Is it driven by a MDX query and uses the MDX UniqueName for each week? Or is it just a drop down of integers?

Comment: I notice you are missing Member_Key here: Cint( STRTOMEMBER(@ToISOWeekNumberOfYear, CONSTRAINED).Member_Key )

Comment: @GregGalloway Member_Key fixed it. If you make it an answer, I can accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you are missing Member_Key here. Change the following:

```
Cint( STRTOMEMBER(@ToISOWeekNumberOfYear, CONSTRAINED) )
```

To:

```
Cint( STRTOMEMBER(@ToISOWeekNumberOfYear, CONSTRAINED).Member_Key )
```